# Correct FIeldCoverter with date time format Filehelpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have a DateTime field which can be null so it needs to be left as a  my question is though

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(NullableDateConverter))]     
public DateTime? ItemNextAvailabilityDate;
```

How does one add the date format

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")]
```

Into the above nullable field remember it must still be a nullable date converter.

Comment: Have you tried adding both attributes?

Comment: @stuartd it says it cant have two field convertors ?.

Comment: I assume _NullableDateConverter_ is a custom converter that you wrote yourself. The FieldConverterAttribute has several constructor overloads which allow you to pass arguments to your custom converter (such as converter-specific format strings, for example), which your custom converter then can use to do what needs to be done...

Comment: @elgonzo i was over complicating it forgot it was a custom handler just changed my datetime.parse to parseexc in that and i am fine.